# How do I substitute inside the visual selection in a vimscript function

Tags: vimscript

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function Foo()
    normal! vi)
    '<,'>s/abc/def/g
endfunction
```

However, when I try to call it, I get "Mark not set" error. What is wrong? Shouldn't the first line set the visual marks?

Comment: I can't figure out why you've got a closing parenthesis after `vi`...

Answer (score 3):

The marks `'<` and `'>` are only set when you *leave* Visual mode.

When you're using Vim interactively, this happens naturally, as you use the `:` to start typing a "substitute" command Vim will leave Visual mode and enter command-line mode. But that's not the case when you're using `normal!` from a function.

You can add an `<Esc>` to leave Visual mode explicitely. You'll need `:execute` to encode the `<Esc>` inside a string.

```
function! Foo()
    execute "normal! vi)\<Esc>"
    '<,'>s/abc/def/g
endfunction
```

---

If desired, you can further improve your function to only replace matches of "abc" inside the selection (inside the `(...)` block) by additionally using the [`/\%V`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25V) marker in your pattern, which only matches at positions inside your last Visual block:

```
function! Foo()
    execute "normal! vi)\<Esc>"
    '<,'>s/\%Vab\%Vc/def/g
endfunction
```